# Fish misbehaves with conda virtual env

Tags: conda, fish, anaconda3

I use fish as the default shell, and conda for installing python packages. I know that there are tons of threads that are related with the issues between conda and fish. But could not find my particular case so here is this question.

When login, I can see the base as the default env. In addition, I can activate a virtual env. But when I do activate the virtual env, fish starts to behave strangely. Such as, the base commands like `ls, kill, etc.` are not recognized :

```
fish: ls: command not found...
Similar command is: 'lz'
/usr/share/fish/functions/ls.fish (line 64):
    command $__fish_ls_command $__fish_ls_color_opt $opt $argv
    ^
in function 'ls'
fish: kill: command not found...
Similar command is: 'kill'
fish:
        command kill $_tide_last_pid 2>/dev/null
        ^
in function '__fish_prompt_orig'
        called on line 51 of file /usr/etc/fish/conf.d/conda.fish
in function 'fish_prompt'
in command substitution
```

This is so annoying. Do you know how to fix this ?

B.R.

p.s. As OS, I use Fedora 36. And all python dependents are installed via `dnf install` ; including conda.

Comment: Your $PATH appears to have been modified and no longer includes the directory where `ls` and `kill` reside. Use `set --show PATH` (no `$`) to figure out what it's set to - it should include /usr/bin as separate element.

Answer (score 1):

The cause of the error is described by faho - see comments. Please give his credit.

In addition, if you want to add `/usr/bin` to your path. Fish has a nice command : `fish_add_path /usr/bin`. It is supposed to work.
For me it didn't work correctly. Due to that I used `set -Ua fish_user_paths /usr/bin/`  which is the old way. And yes my fish version is up-to-date (3.4.1).